# Is there any clean way to code a group of || testing to see if the value of a variable is in one of them?

Tags: javascript

I have code like this:

```
if (view == 'delete' || view =='edit' || view == 'new') {}
```

Is there a more clean way that I can code this without using an external library. It just does not look too good to have all the || and maybe more later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use indexOf (won't work on ancient IE versions):

```
if (["delete", "edit", "new"].indexOf( view ) >= 0) { alert("ME");}
```

Comment: This is not any way cleaner or easier to understand than what OP has written. If anything other than using `===` instead of `==` his or her way of writing it is much cleaner and expressive.

Comment: @rdodev, its a matter of opinion. I come across this compacted expression shorthand in js very often, and I personally use it and like it.

Comment: indexOf support http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.indexOf

Comment: @rambocoder it's also less efficient as it will check all possibilities for index, whereas the original boolean form has short-circuit once a match has been found. http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html#the_fastest_conditionals

Comment: @rdodev indexof() will absolutely stop searching after finding a match. Regardless, I, and many others place a relatively high value on readable and concise code, and a relatively low value on unwarranted micro optimizations.

Comment: I'd be really really amazed if any major browser implemented an `indexOf` that doesn't stop at the very first match.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use regular expression:

```
if (/^(delete|edit|new)$/.test(view)) {
    // true
}
```