# Javascript: "a === b or c"?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

I would like to check whether variable `a` is equal to `b` or `c`.
Of course I know the explicit way to do this;

```
a === b || a === c
```

but is there a shorthand way of doing this in **Javascript**?  I mean, for example,

```
a === (b || c)
```

does *not* work.

I found similar questions here

- [Short hand to do something like: if($variable == 1 || $variable == "whatever" || $variable == '492') .](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205377/short-hand-to-do-something-like-ifvariable-1-variable-whatever)
- [PHP: If a equals b or c or d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11611540/php-if-a-equals-b-or-c-or-d)

but they are talking about PHP.

Comment: Just FYI, this question was already [asked today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20295851/218196) (and closed as well).

Comment: oh thanks, that's also helpful

Comment: oops, thanks anyway :)

Comment: How is what you'are asking not short?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a shorter or more concise way of doing this in regular JavaScript.

An alternative would be to do a ternary, but this is arguably far less readable, so I would stick with the expression you have.

Ternary:

```
a === b ? true : a === c
```

Advised, as in your question

```
a === b || a === c
```

Comment: +1 Correct, there's no reasonable way in JavaScript that's more brief unless you define and reuse a function. (I think you meant "expression" rather than "expansion"...?)

Comment: @ChrisAlexander, welcome to the site. Great first answer.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is as you described `a===b||a===c` all other method can only expand your code. So, Use `a===b||a===c` instead of using any other .

Answer (score -4):

```
((a === (b||c))
```

its the shortest way

Comment: Short is useless if it is not equivalent. Take `a = false`, `b = false` and `c = true`. Then `a === (b || c)` is false, while `a === b || a === c` is true.